# How to Move Cursor using CTRL + Arrows?

Tags: cursor

I'm using `Terminator` which is Terminal Emulator and I want to add CTRL + Arrows shortcut instead of Alt + b or Alt +c

Comment: It can be done in shell config file, like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (tell me which shell you use first, please). If it's for Bash or Zsh, I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

First step, check if those shortcuts are recognized by your terminal :
type <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd> on your terminal, and see what it does.
For me, it writes `^[[1;5D` and `^[[1;5C`
(where `^[` is just **one** character, similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd>).
If it writes nothing or something else, it means those shortcuts are already used.

If you are using `Bash`, you can add (copy and paste it) to your `~/.bashrc` file :

```
bind '"\033[1;5D":"\033b"'
bind '"\033[1;5C":"\033c"'
```

If you are using `Zsh`, you can add (copy and paste it) to your `~/.zshrc` file :

```
bindkey -s '\e[1;5D' '\eb'
bindkey -s '\e[1;5C' '\ec'
```

It will make <kbd>Ctrl + Left</kbd> have the behavior of <kbd>Alt + b</kbd>,
and <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd> have the behavior of <kbd>Alt + c</kbd>.

This method is supposed to work with almost every terminal (I tested it with `Terminator` to be sure), and mostly depends on your shell.